# How to denote an altitude or an angle bisector of a triangle

Tags: notation, plane-geometry

> Consider the following situation: ($CH\perp AB, H \in AB$). 
>   [image]

I was always wondering if we should write that $CH=h_c$ or $CH\equiv h_c$. I am not sure which one to use when I am writing my solutions. Which one do you prefer and why? If $CL$ is the angle bisector of $\angle ACB$ ($L \in AB$), should I write $CL=l_{\angle C}$ or $CL\equiv l_{\angle C}$?

Answer (score 0):

Here $CH$ and $h_c$ are numbers: they are a length of an altitude.

Thus, it's better to write $$CH=h_c.$$

If we want to say that points $A$ and $B$ are the same, so it's better to write $$A\equiv B.$$
By the way, we can write $$\{A\}=\{B\}.$$

I think, all these are not so important. We always know from the context  about what we say.

Comment: Why $A\equiv B$ ? I would write simply $A=B$, because $\equiv$ is usually a congruence relation between segments.

Comment: @Kulisty Because $A$ and $B$ are not numbers. Also, they are not sets. If $a$ and $b$ are segments, so we can write $a=b$ as an equality of two sets.

Comment: Well, whatever $A$ and $B$ are they can be equal, can't they?

Comment: @Kulisty Numbers can be, sets can be, but points they are coincident points. Here $A\equiv B$ it's a coincidence of $A$ and $B$. Points they are not numbers or sets. But I think, all these are not so important. We always know from the context about what we say.

Comment: I disagree. If you look at Tarski's axioms for geometry, they are formulated in first order logic with equality and points are the domain of discourse. There are other approaches as well but this is the first time I see someone forbidding to put equality between points. Does it come from some known theory?

Comment: @Kulisty Am I forbidding something? See please better my post. I explained why I think so.  By the way,  if we look at Tarski's axioms for geometry, so we understand immediately about what we say. Try to understand about what I said. Good luck! Bye.

Comment: You introduce coincident points which is some kind of relation. You should define it some way or add some axioms about it. IMO the properties of "coincident" points do not differ at all from equal points, hence it is more convienent to just use equality. Good luck!